# StyleCop SA1202 - Internal property with private set

Tags: stylecop

I'm getting a StyleCop error that I'm unsure how to fix, other than adding a suppression message on my class, which is bad practice. If you know how to fix this, or know if this is just a StyleCop bug or flaw, please let me know.

Note: I don't know if this makes a difference, but I am using the Visual StyleCop extension by HEISER Christophe for Visual Studio 2015.

I have an internal class with internal properties. Example:

```
internal bool Property1 { get; set; }
internal int Property2 { get; private set; }
```

Regardless of the fact that all my properties have the internal accessor, and are ordered within the class properly, according to the [StyleCop](http://www.stylecop.com/docs/SA1202.html) and [Visual StyleCop](https://github.com/Visual-Stylecop/Visual-StyleCop/wiki/SA1202) Ordering Rules documentation, I still receive the SA1202 error "All private properties must be placed after all internal properties". That error doesn't make sense to me since all my properties have internal access. I assume it's because of the private set, but even if I order all the properties with private setters after (or even before) properties without private setters, I keep receiving the same error. It almost seems to me that StyleCop does not recognize or work properly with this situation.

Any ideas on how to fix this (without a suppression message on the class) or if this is just a bug/flaw in StyleCop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jafo, could you paste the complete code of your class here : [Visual StyleCop - GitHub - Issue 47](https://github.com/Visual-Stylecop/Visual-StyleCop/issues/47) because it works on my side with the following code :

```
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <copyright file="InternalClass.cs" company="TestCompany">
//   MS-PL
// </copyright>
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
namespace ConsoleApplication10
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Test internal class.
    /// </summary>
    internal class InternalClass
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether the property one.
        /// </summary>
        internal bool Property1 { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the property two.
        /// </summary>
        internal int Property2 { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right, moving the parameters to the configuration you showed in your example did not product a StyleCop error. I'm pretty sure I tried this configuration before, but it's possible I missed moving a parameter as there are ~20 in my code. But also, I could not find any documentation directly on how to order parameters in this situation. I appreciate your reply! (I should also state that I updated Visual StyleCop this morning, which may or may not have been a factor)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be bug with the Visual StyleCop extension.

This builds ok using the [StyleCop.MSBuild](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StyleCop.MSBuild/) implementation.

I've added this as an issue on [Github](https://github.com/Visual-Stylecop/Visual-StyleCop/issues/47).